# Drupal users by role - sql query

Tags: drupal-7

I need a sql query count list of how many users have more than one role (by role and by role combination) eg:

admin, author: 50
admin, author, annoymouse user, authenticated user: 20
members, authenticated user: 100
etc

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

MySQL query is:

```
mysql> SELECT  ur.rid, r.name, count(*) as TOT  from users_roles ur    INNER JOIN  role r ON r.rid = ur.rid     group by ur.rid  ;

+-----+---------------+-----+
| rid | name          | TOT |
+-----+---------------+-----+
|   3 | administrator |   2 |
|   4 | tst           |   1 |
+-----+---------------+-----+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

As alternative option, you have the [Views Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). Create a new view, type: user. Enable and play with aggregation on the Role field